# How do I prompt a user to select 2 elements from an array and combine them?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a jobArray[] with 5 jobs. Each job contains a description, hours to complete the job and hourly pay for each job.

I have to prompt the user to input 2 jobs they would like to combine. The combined job will have the combined description, hoursToComplete and a calculated hourly pay based on the 2 jobs selected.

I'm unsure how to go from here in regards to taking the users input and matching it to the element in the array and combining it. Is there a way to search the array to match the users input with a loop?

Below is my code and the combineJobs() module is where I'm having the user input which 2 jobs they would like to combine.

```
//combining jobs
    public static void CombineJobs()
    {


        string input1, input2;
        Console.WriteLine("Select 2 jobs from the array and combine them.");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        //printing out array elements
        for (int i = 0; i < jobArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Job " + i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the first index");
        input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the second index");
        input2 = Console.ReadLine();
    }

}


}
```

In the combineJobs() module I print out the array indexes for the user to choose from. Here is part of my second class also

```
class Job : IComparable<Job>
{
public string Description { get; set; }

public int hoursToComplete { get; set; }

public double hourlyRate { get; set; }

public double totalFee { get; set; }

public Job(string description,
            int hours,
            double hourRate,
            double fee)
{
    Description = description;
    hoursToComplete = hoursToComplete;
    hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    totalFee = totalFee;

}

public Job()
{
    // TODO: Complete member initialization
}

public static Job operator +(Job first, Job second)
{
    String newDescription = first.Description + " and " + second.Description;
    int newHoursToComplete = first.hoursToComplete + second.hoursToComplete;
    double newHourlyRate = first.hourlyRate + second.hourlyRate / 2;
    double newTotalFee = first.totalFee + second.totalFee;
    return (new Job(newDescription, newHoursToComplete, newHourlyRate, newTotalFee));

}
```

Sorry if this is a lot, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First thing is first.  You need to output the jobs to the console so the user can know what they want to select.  You should probably create a Display method in the Job class which displays the properties of the job in a user-friendly, readable format.

Comment: I have this created already, should I include it in the original post?

Comment: For completeness, you should probably do so.  But assuming you have that down, why not loop through the Jobs array in a different method than CombineJobs?  Maybe the Main method or another method that Main calls.  Then, prompt the user to enter the index of two of the jobs they want to combine.  You can do this by prompting two times, prompt once and ask to enter with a space, etc.  Then, pass those two numbers to the CombineJobs method.

Comment: I added code so it prompts twice, but unsure how I would  loop through my array

Comment: Once you have the two indexes that the user selected, you do not need to do anymore looping.  You can access the Job object in the JobArray using the input received.